# Emacs doesn't display JPEG files correctly

Tags: microsoft-windows, emacs24.4, display, images

`PNG` images displays well on my computer, but the `JPEG` images are displayed incorrectly as small boxes as shown in the following image:

[image]

I'm running `Emacs 24.4` under `Windows 7`. And I compiled `libpng16.dll` and `libjpeg-9.dll` myself.

I got the `PNG` library from [here](http://libpng.sourceforge.net/) and compiled it using `Visual Studio 13`. And I got the `JPEG` library from [here](http://www.ijg.org/files/) and compiled it using `MinGW`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the self compiled `libjpeg-9.dll`. It is solved by downloading `dll` files from [ezwinports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/) as [recommended](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/):

```
Emacs can also support some other image formats with appropriate
libraries.  These libraries are all available on the following sites:

1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/
   -- leaner, more up-to-date builds, only for 32-bit Emacs
2. http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php
   http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php
   -- the GTK project site; offers much fatter builds, but includes
      64-bit DLLs (from the 2nd URL)
3. GnuWin32 project -- very old builds, not recommended
```